# How can I select a state of a Button(as2)?

Tags: actionscript-2

One more time i need your help.

I´m working in a project which have many buttons, with textfield inside of them. I need to change the text of those textfields. How can I do it using as2?

Regards

Comment: Please add a little more detail about what you're using, the code you've written or classes you struggle with. Post some code that can help us to understand the exact case you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

TextFieldNameHere.text = "test";

or

TextFieldNameHere.text = StringVariableNameHere